# How to use shapefile to categorize set of coordinate by neighborhood?

Tags: shapefile, coordinates, pandas

Just a disclaimer, this is my first project with GIS so this may be really trivial. I have looked around but haven't found resources that were helpful to me.

Currently I have a list of NYC coordinates that I would like to categorize by Neighborhood. I've seen that shapefiles are a good option but I haven't worked with them before and I havent found anything like this online.

First off, here is my dataset:

[image]

At the end of the day, I'd like to create an additional column that will categorize the `(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)` coordinate into a specific NYC neighborhood.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Unfortunately, you've provided a *picture* of your data, not the data itself, so no one can help you without re-typing it (which is not likely). This really is a basic task, for which many tutorials exist. GIS SE is a problem-solving site, where some effort is demonstrated toward solving the problem. Please [Edit] the question to specify what GIS software you are attempting to use, and if this is a coding task, provide the code you've developed to date, along with a description of the error your are encountering.